# caffe: Net not converging when replacing AlexNet with VGG16 but everything else is the same

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, vgg-net

I have been using the AlexNet for a pixel-wise regression task (depth estimation). Now I wanted to replace the AlexNet with the VGG net since it is ought to be better.

This is the AlexNet I used:

```
layer {
  name: "train-data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  data_param {
    source: "../data/.."
    batch_size: 4
    backend: LMDB
  }
  transform_param {
     mean_value: 127
  }
}
layer {
  name: "train-depth"
  type: "Data"
  top: "gt"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    # feature scaling coefficient: this maps [0, 255] to [0, 1]
    scale: 0.00390625
  }
  data_param {
    source: "../data/.."
    batch_size: 4
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "val-data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  data_param {
    source: "../data/.."
    batch_size: 4
    backend: LMDB
  }
  transform_param {
     mean_value: 127
  }
}
layer {
  name: "val-depth"
  type: "Data"
  top: "gt"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  transform_param {
    # feature scaling coefficient: this maps [0, 255] to [0, 1]
    scale: 0.00390625
  }
  data_param {
    source: "../data/.."
    batch_size: 4
    backend: LMDB
  }
}

# CONVOLUTIONAL
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 0.02
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult:  0.02
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 96
    kernel_size: 11
    stride: 4
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv1"
}
layer {
  name: "norm1"
  type: "LRN"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "norm1"
  lrn_param {
    local_size: 5
    alpha: 0.0001
    beta: 0.75
  }
}
layer {
  name: "pool1"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "norm1"
  top: "pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "conv2"
  param {
    lr_mult:  0.02
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult:  0.02
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    engine: CAFFE
    num_output: 256
    pad: 2
    kernel_size: 5
    group: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "conv2"
}
layer {
  name: "norm2"
  type: "LRN"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "norm2"
  lrn_param {
    local_size: 5
    alpha: 0.0001
    beta: 0.75
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv3"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "norm2"
  top: "conv3"
  param {
    lr_mult:  0.02
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult:  0.02
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 384
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu3"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "conv3"
}
layer {
  name: "conv4"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "conv4"
  param {
    lr_mult:  0.02
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult:  0.02
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 384
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    group: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu4"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv4"
  top: "conv4"
}
layer {
  name: "conv5"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv4"
  top: "conv5"
  param {
    lr_mult:  0.02
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult:  0.02
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    group: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu5"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv5"
  top: "conv5"
}
layer {
  name: "pool5"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv5"
  top: "pool5"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}

# MAIN

layer {
  name: "fc-main"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "pool5"
  top: "fc-main"
  param {
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 1024
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
      std: 0.005
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu6"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "fc-main"
  top: "fc-main"
  relu_param {
    engine: CAFFE
  }
}
layer {
  name: "drop6"
 type: "Dropout"
  bottom: "fc-main"
  top: "fc-main"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc-depth"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc-main"
  top: "fc-depth"
  param {
    decay_mult: 1
    lr_mult:  0.2
  }
  param {
    lr_mult:  0.2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 1369
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.001
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.5
    }
  }
}
layer {
    name: "reshape"
    type: "Reshape"
    bottom: "fc-depth"
    top: "depth"
    reshape_param {
      shape {
        dim: 0  # copy the dimension from below
        dim: 1
        dim: 37
        dim: 37 # infer it from the other dimensions
      }
    }
  }



layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "EuclideanLoss"
  bottom: "depth"
  bottom: "gt"
  top: "loss"
  loss_weight: 1
}
```

This is the VGG I am using:

```
layer {
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1_1"
  name: "conv1_1"
  type: "Convolution"
  param {
      lr_mult: 0.001
      decay_mult: 1
    }
    param {
      lr_mult: 0.001
      decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 64
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  bottom: "conv1_1"
  top: "conv1_1"
  name: "relu1_1"
  type: "ReLU"
}
layer {
  bottom: "conv1_1"
  top: "conv1_2"
  name: "conv1_2"
  type: "Convolution"
  param {
      lr_mult: 0.001
      decay_mult: 1
    }
    param {
      lr_mult: 0.001
      decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 64
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  bottom: "conv1_2"
  top: "conv1_2"
  name: "relu1_2"
  type: "ReLU"
}
layer {
  bottom: "conv1_2"
  top: "pool1"
  name: "pool1"
  type: "Pooling"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "conv2_1"
  name: "conv2_1"
  type: "Convolution"
  param {
      lr_mult: 0.001
      decay_mult: 1
    }
    param {
      lr_mult: 0.001
      decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 128
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  bottom: "conv2_1"
  top: "conv2_1"
  name: "relu2_1"
  type: "ReLU"
}
layer {
  bottom: "conv2_1"
  top: "conv2_2"
  name: "conv2_2"
  type: "Convolution"
  param {
      lr_mult: 0.001
      decay_mult: 1
    }
    param {
      lr_mult: 0.001
      decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 128
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  bottom: "conv2_2"
  top: "conv2_2"
  name: "relu2_2"
  type: "ReLU"
}
layer {
  bottom: "conv2_2"
  top: "pool2"
  name: "pool2"
  type: "Pooling"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  bottom: "pool2"
  top: "conv3_1"
  name: "conv3_1"
  type: "Convolution"
  param {
      lr_mult: 0.001
      decay_mult: 1
    }
    param {
      lr_mult: 0.001
      decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  bottom: "conv3_1"
  top: "conv3_1"
  name: "relu3_1"
  type: "ReLU"
}
layer {
  bottom: "conv3_1"
  top: "conv3_2"
  name: "conv3_2"
  type: "Convolution"
  param {
      lr_mult: 0.001
      decay_mult: 1
    }
    param {
      lr_mult: 0.001
      decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  bottom: "conv3_2"
  top: "conv3_2"
  name: "relu3_2"
  type: "ReLU"
}
layer {
  bottom: "conv3_2"
  top: "conv3_3"
  name: "conv3_3"
  type: "Convolution"
  param {
      lr_mult: 0.001
      decay_mult: 1
    }
    param {
      lr_mult: 0.001
      decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  bottom: "conv3_3"
  top: "conv3_3"
  name: "relu3_3"
  type: "ReLU"
}
layer {
  bottom: "conv3_3"
  top: "pool3"
  name: "pool3"
  type: "Pooling"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  bottom: "pool3"
  top: "conv4_1"
  name: "conv4_1"
  type: "Convolution"
  param {
      lr_mult: 0.001
      decay_mult: 1
    }
    param {
      lr_mult: 0.001
      decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  bottom: "conv4_1"
  top: "conv4_1"
  name: "relu4_1"
  type: "ReLU"
}
layer {
  bottom: "conv4_1"
  top: "conv4_2"
  name: "conv4_2"
  type: "Convolution"
  param {
      lr_mult: 0.001
      decay_mult: 1
    }
    param {
      lr_mult: 0.001
      decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  bottom: "conv4_2"
  top: "conv4_2"
  name: "relu4_2"
  type: "ReLU"
}
layer {
  bottom: "conv4_2"
  top: "conv4_3"
  name: "conv4_3"
  type: "Convolution"
  param {
      lr_mult: 0.001
      decay_mult: 1
    }
    param {
      lr_mult: 0.001
      decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  bottom: "conv4_3"
  top: "conv4_3"
  name: "relu4_3"
  type: "ReLU"
}
layer {
  bottom: "conv4_3"
  top: "pool4"
  name: "pool4"
  type: "Pooling"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  bottom: "pool4"
  top: "conv5_1"
  name: "conv5_1"
  type: "Convolution"
  param {
      lr_mult: 0.001
      decay_mult: 1
    }
    param {
      lr_mult: 0.001
      decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  bottom: "conv5_1"
  top: "conv5_1"
  name: "relu5_1"
  type: "ReLU"
}
layer {
  bottom: "conv5_1"
  top: "conv5_2"
  name: "conv5_2"
  type: "Convolution"
  param {
      lr_mult: 0.001
      decay_mult: 1
    }
    param {
      lr_mult: 0.001
      decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  bottom: "conv5_2"
  top: "conv5_2"
  name: "relu5_2"
  type: "ReLU"
}
layer {
  bottom: "conv5_2"
  top: "conv5_3"
  name: "conv5_3"
  type: "Convolution"
  param {
      lr_mult: 0.001
      decay_mult: 1
    }
    param {
      lr_mult: 0.001
      decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  bottom: "conv5_3"
  top: "conv5_3"
  name: "relu5_3"
  type: "ReLU"
}
layer {
  bottom: "conv5_3"
  top: "pool5"
  name: "pool5"
  type: "Pooling"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  bottom: "pool5"
  top: "fc6"
  name: "fc6"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  param {
      lr_mult: 0.1
      decay_mult: 1
    }
    param {
      lr_mult: 0.1
      decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 4096
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.001
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.5
    }
  }
}
layer {
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc6"
  name: "relu6"
  type: "ReLU"
  relu_param {
    engine: CAFFE
  }
}

layer {
  name: "drop6"
  type: "Dropout"
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc6"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}

layer {
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc7"
  name: "fc7"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  param {
      lr_mult: 0.1
      decay_mult: 1
    }
    param {
      lr_mult: 0.1
      decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 1369
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.001
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.5
    }
  }
}

layer {
    name: "reshape"
    type: "Reshape"
    bottom: "fc7"
    top: "depth"
    reshape_param {
      shape {
        dim: 0  # copy the dimension from below
        dim: 1
        dim: 37
        dim: 37 # infer it from the other dimensions
      }
    }
  }

layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "EuclideanLoss"
  bottom: "depth"
  bottom: "gt"
  top: "loss"
  loss_weight: 1
}
```

learning_rate is: 0.0005

When training the AlexNet the loss converges to roughly 5 and when using the VGG the net does not converge at all. It always stays at 30, even though I have been decreasing the learning_rate and even decreased mult_lr. Does anyone have any ideas what else could be wrong? I am 100% sure that only the .prototxt files are different, everything else is exactly the same.

Comment: try removing the top fully connected layers. they have too many parameters

Comment: I have already removed one top layer of the VGG. Are you saying I should remove the "fc6" one so that I only have one fully-connected layer with num_output=1369 or shall I reduce the num output fc6 to 1024? @Shai

Comment: And second question how do you know that kind of stuff? Is it just because you have the comparison or would you have said that anyway cause my last layer has 1369 num_outputs but my second one has 4096 which obviuosly is like 3 times as big as 1369. @Shai

Comment: your output shape is 37x37 I suppose it is closely related to the input shape. why not leave your net as a fully convolutional one? why insisting on a fully connected layer on top?

Comment: Because of a paper that I tried to copy. My input is 128x128 or 298x298 I have tried both things. So if I inrease the shape of my output for example 60x60. The question was why the AlexNet is working perfectly and the VGG16 is not even though the paper says so. Have a look at Figure 1 in [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.4734v4.pdf) @Shai

Comment: "try removing the top fully connected layers. they have too many parameters" what do you mean by this? I mean the AlexNet is working fine. But the VGG16 is not even though they are quite similar. Do you have any other ideas? @Shai

Comment: I'm afraid I don't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is known that VGG is hard to train from scratch for large networks: in the paper of Simonyan and Zisserman, it is said in section 3.1. In practice, they first train a "small" (A) configuration with random weights then use these weights to initialize larger networks (C-D-E). Moreover, you may need more data to train VGG than AlexNet.

In your case, you may consider to fine-tune VGG16 rather than learning it from scratch. Or let use googlenet  that is much lighter (and easier to train) and lead to similar performance on several problems I tested.

Comment: Oh thank you that is an interesting answer. What I have been trying to do is to train 100 images which I thought should be little enough to be learned by heart by the network.
Hm fine-tuning might not be possilbe since I want to use an input of 128x128. But I might try a larger dataset. Or I will try the GoogleNet. Do you have a link for the googlenet for caffe since I thought GoogleNet was a really deep net rather than a "light" net

Comment: [link](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/models/bvlc_googlenet) if you mean that net then it is not very light in my opinion :D At least not compared to the VGG net. But thanks for the answer!

Comment: In terms of number of operation needed for a forward pass as well as in terms of number of weights, I think it is lighter: see [here](https://culurciello.github.io/tech/2016/06/04/nets.html) for example.